# Correct way of using adapter with Glide

Tags: android, adapter, android-glide

When loading about 40 images (resolution 1080x1920) with Glide , I am getting out of memory errors while I am scrolling trough my RecyclerView. I am using small thumbnails on my gallery to fill up images.

Is this the correct way to use Glide in an Adapter ? :

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<String> images;
private Context mContext;
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView thumbnail;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }
}


public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> images) {
    mContext = context;
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final String image = images.get(position);

    Glide.with(mContext).load(image).asBitmap().format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).thumbnail(0.1f).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.ac_icon_300).dontAnimate().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
            holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(resource);


        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
  }
}
```

Recyclerview :

```
    images = getData();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new    GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4147212 byte allocation with 34056 free bytes and 33KB until OOM  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
```

Comment: use `.Override(width, height)` to resize the image.. its always OOM if very high res is loaded.. and please check your layout if there is nested scrollview exists.